# what is the best way to compare two huge csv files in perl using hash DataStructure?

Tags: perl, hash

string.txt contains the string (this data is unique) that has to be searched in second file ( input.csv) and 
when there is a match it has to redirect the output to a file.

Now I have created the code to do this , But when i run this script breaks saying "**Out of memory**"

Can someone please let me know the best way to do it with max speed and bypassing "**Out of memory**" error .

I believe its due to huge size of the file , and the complex hash data structure I am building there.

> Record count of string.txt = 5611273 ( ~100 MB )
>
> record count of input.csv  = 65261242 ( ~2.4 GB)

**Below is the sample file content**

**string.txt**

```
alpha
beta
delta
gamma
bob
tom
jerry
```

**input.csv**

```
alpha|a1|b2|c3
delta|a2|b2|c3
beta|a1|b2|c3
gamma|a1|b2|c3
omega|a1|b2|c3
alpha|a1|b2|c3
delta|a2|b2|c3
```

**Sample Hash DataStructure**

```
   'gamma' => {
                       '4' => [
                                'a1',
                                'b2',
                                'c3'
                              ]
                     },
          'delta' => {
                       '7' => [
                                'a2',
                                'b2',
                                'c3'
                              ],
                       '2' => [
                                'a2',
                                'b2',
                                'c3'
                              ]
                     },
```

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my %hash;
my $key;
local $"="|"; #"
my $count=1;

open(my $INPUT_FH,'<','/home/chidori/input.csv') or die "Can't open the file $!\n";

while(my $line = <$INPUT_FH>) {
  chomp($line);
  my @line = split (/\|/,$line);
  my $key = shift @line;
  push (@{$hash{$key}{$count}},@line);
  $count++;
}

#print Dumper (\%hash);
close($INPUT_FH);

open(my $STRING_FH,'<','/home/chidori/string.txt') or die "Can't open the file $!\n";

while( my $search_string = <$STRING_FH> ) {
  chomp($search_string);
  if (exists $hash{$search_string} ) {
    foreach my $k( keys %{$hash{$search_string}}) {
      my @line_to_print;
      push (@line_to_print,$search_string);
      push (@line_to_print,@{$hash{$search_string}{$k}});
      print "@line_to_print\n";  #Temporarily printing it to STDOUT. But need to redirect it to a outfile
    }
  }
}

close($STRING_FH)
```

Comment: There is two solutions to your problem: 1. add more memories; 2. split your `input.csv`, process them one by one, then combine the results. By the way, one way to split that input is putting all lines starting with `a` to file `a.csv`, all lines starting with `b` to `b.csv`, and so on.

Comment: @mpapec , Please tell me how i can achieve it

Comment: @LeeDuhem On basis i shall split ? Based on size of the file ? Why is that my Hash datastructure causes the script run out of memory . Please tell me

Comment: I was checking similar issue in google , and there i saw some suggestions of using http://search.cpan.org/~pmqs/DB_File/DB_File.pm

Comment: @chidori Your input file has about 2.4G data, and you need to keep all of them in the main memory of your computer, so you need a 64-bit operating system and about 3G memory. Or you have to split your input file first, process those smaller files one by one, then combine the results.

Comment: Using database is another way to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: @LeeDuhem Can you please tell me how i can achieve this using DB. I have access all cpan modules and also have access to database. What would be best approach to achieve this using database.

Comment: I can show you that method (though I am not sure that is the best approach). Also you may be disappointed to find out that I am not offer the working code, only a description of that method. Anyway, please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chidori, there are several possible solutions, one of them trying to stay close to what you already have. An other one would treat the whole thing as a database.

So, here are first a few comments about your strategy:

- At this moment, you try to build a huge data-structure from the 2.4GB file and after that, you read in the smaller, to see if there is a match. You could do it the other way around, read in the 'string.txt' into a hash, with the keys as each line of the file and whatever value (undef ?).
- If you really want to use the input file as a CSV, with the '|' as a separator, `use Text::CSV` where possible. If it is a plain ASCII like file, then a split on '|' is appropriate and faster.
- Since you want to print your @line_to_print, there is no real need to create that array first, push things onto it and then print out the elements. `print` provides a so called 'list context' and thus `print $search_string, @{$hash->{$search_string}{$k}}` would be sufficient and speed up again a bit.
- Perl does have a built-in line-counter when reading a file

I hope this gives enough hints on how you can get it work in the limited memory constraints and even speed up the thing. There is then no need to sort the files first, the hash mechanisms have super fast lookup methods itself.

> It's a rainy day, a nice moment to do some Perl coding if you need
>   more help.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your csv file by the first value, and then read `string.txt` into memory, and process csv file in the while loop.

Comment: String.txt and input csv don't have the same number of records . Also not necessary that data in string.txt would be always present in input csv.

Comment: @chidori that is why you make hash out of string.txt, and print only these csv lines which could be found in such hash.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping [working set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_set) small enough is the key to process huge data files on a machine with limited memory resources.

In the problem descripted in the original post, keeping all the contents of `input.csv` in memory, in other words, using all the contents of that file as working set, will get a working set too large to fit in memory. This is the cause of that "Out of memory" error. To solve this problem, we need to reduce the size of that working set.

Because we are only interested in the lines of `input.csv` that their first fields are in `string.txt`, so we can use that `string.txt` as a filter to filter out the lines of `input.csv` that we are not interested.

If the result of that filtering is still too large, we can split it to multiple files, process them one by one, then combine these results to get the final result.

1. read `string.txt` to create a filter
2. split input data file

   ```
   while (readline) {
           discard current line unless it in filter
           first_char = extract first character of current line
           store current line to file named first_char
   }
   ```

   It would be much simpler if we can open a file for each entity in `string.txt`. We cannot do that because file descriptor also a limited resource for a process.

   If after this step some data files are still too large to fit in memory, we need to split them recursively by using similar method.
3. process each smaller data file, and generate a result file for it
4. combine all these result files to the final result file

Instead of split input data file manually, you could use a database, and let the database management system do all those works for you. To solve the problem descripted in the original post, you can create a table in the database

```
    ID  | VALUE
    ----------
    id1 | val1
    id2 | val2
```

here `ID`s are the first fields of lines of `input.csv`, and `VALUE`s the rest of the corresponding lines.

If you want to use `string.txt` as a filter, you can insert all lines (as `ID`, with empty `VALUE`) of that files into that table first.

After that, you can process the input data file `input.csv` line by line:

```
    while (readline) {
            id = extract first field of current line
            search for record with `ID` equals id in table
            if that record exists, update it with a new value;
            else insert a new record
    }
```

When you finished data import, you can get the final result

```
    select all record from that table
    write them to a file one by one
```

Comment: If I have to copy this 2.4gb file into db , how much space would be required . I am using sybase db.

Comment: @chidori I do not know. But normally it will cost about 3G harddisk space.

Comment: I have around 10gb space for db.. but I think I will go with splitting the input.csv into smaller files and proceed further